# mysqli_num_rows returns 1 no matter what

Tags: php, mysqli

When I do a SQL search in phpMyAdmin (substituting the variable for the actual value) it returns the correct row number but when using PHP to return this value it always returns 1 no matter what.  Thanks in advance.

```
function user_exists($username) {
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test');
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `new_base` WHERE `username`='$username'");
    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    echo $row_cnt;
    mysqli_free_result($query);
    mysqli_close($link);
}
```

Comment: your reading how many rows the `SELECT` returned not the row number

Comment: It has been asked  zillion times already...

Comment: `COUNT` is a group function.  It combines the rows into one result.  What *exactly* do you want this query to return?  You probably need a `GROUP BY` in there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `COUNT(*)` you *always get one row returned even if the count is zero*.

You either:

1. Want to remove the `count(*)` and then use `mysqli_num_rows()`
   or
2. Get the result of `count(*)`

.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
echo $row['COUNT(`user_id`)'];
```

Comment: Thanks, went with your first suggestion

Comment: I fixed a slight typo there John, after Googling something for another question today. Let's see if they come your way ;-) Question being http://stackoverflow.com/q/39002738/

Comment: @Fred-ii- Good catch!

Comment: @JohnConde :-) I've my best glasses on today.

Answer (score 1):

Count retrives a **single row**. Try testing the SQL in phpmyadmin and see the result.
This single row returned by the query has the number you are looking for.

I suggest also doing something like

```
SELECT COUNT('user_id') AS user_matches FROM ....
```

This way you can access the via the 'user_matches' key.

*I would **not** recommend using SELECT * FROM ... * with the num_rows, this would be very slow compared to a count().

Comment: in this particular case it won't be very slow but actually the same. But in general you are right